# How to add custom data in the output of GET API to get children of configurable product in Magento 2.3?

Tags: configurable-product, rest-api, magento2.3, simple-product

To get children of Configurable Product, I'm using following API

> /V1/configurable-products/{{SKU}}/children

I'm getting following output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3234,
        "sku": "ABC1006",
        "name": "ABC Config Product",
        "attribute_set_id": 4,
        "price": 2400,
        "status": 1,
        "type_id": "simple",
        "created_at": "2018-12-17 13:27:58",
        "updated_at": "2018-12-18 11:06:28",
        "weight": 1,
        "product_links": [],
        "tier_prices": [],
        "custom_attributes": [
            {
                "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
                "value": "2"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "required_options",
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "category_ids",
                "value": [
                    "173"
                ]
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "has_options",
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "brand",
                "value": "399"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "short_description",
                "value": "<ul></ul>"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "image",
                "value": "/h/a/hamster-ball-32cm_7.png"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "small_image",
                "value": "/h/a/hamster-ball-32cm_7.png"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
                "value": "/h/a/hamster-ball-32cm_7.png"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "swatch_image",
                "value": "/h/a/hamster-ball-32cm_7.png"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "url_key",
                "value": "savic-hamster-ball-extra-large"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "msrp_display_actual_price_type",
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "size_swatch",
                "value": "213"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to add one more key pair (type=string) in the above json output.
Where should I make changes to get the results.

Comment: I think you need to make the changes into the model somewhere which is responsible for this response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add an attribute with its value using extension attribute model as follows.

Add attribute code to extension attribute set by creating following file

> Vendor\YourModule\etc\extension_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface">
        <attribute code="custom_attr_code" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Now set your custom value by overriding

> Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\LinkManagement

using dependency injection

> Vendor\YourModule\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\LinkManagement" type="Vendor\YourModule\Model\LinkManagement" />
</config>
```

Rewriting GetChildren method with your custom value

> Vendor\YourModule\Model\LinkManagement.php

```
    public function getChildren($sku)
        {
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
            $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
            if ($product->getTypeId() != \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
                return [];
            }

            /** @var \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $productTypeInstance */
            $productTypeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
            $productTypeInstance->setStoreFilter($product->getStoreId(), $product);

            $childrenList = [];
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $child */
            foreach ($productTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($product) as $child) {
                $attributes = [];
                foreach ($child->getAttributes() as $attribute) {
                    $attrCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
                    $value = $child->getDataUsingMethod($attrCode) ?: $child->getData($attrCode);
                    if (null !== $value) {
                        $attributes[$attrCode] = $value;
                    }
                }
                $attributes['store_id'] = $child->getStoreId();
                /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $productDataObject */
                $productDataObject = $this->productFactory->create();
                $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
                    $productDataObject,
                    $attributes,
                    \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface::class
                );


//Start of custom code
                $extensionAttributes = $productDataObject->getExtensionAttributes();
                $extensionAttributes->setCustomAttrCode('customValue');
                $productDataObject->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
//End of custom code


                $childrenList[] = $productDataObject;
            }
            return $childrenList;
        }
```